# Docker Thinks Port 5000 is In Use but npm Doesn't

Tags: docker

My question was closed so I am posting this again because ...
**The other answers have not helped because killing the process that seems to own port 5000 does not help. Plus I can use port 5000 without Docker**.**

Why can't Docker use port 5000 when npm can?

I am trying to run a docker container on macOS. It works when I run `npm start` but not when I run it as a container. It also seems to work if I switch to port 5001.

```
> docker run -p 5000:5000 app-flask ERRO[0000] error waiting for
> container: context canceled  docker: Error response from daemon: Ports
> are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen
> tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use.
```

I don't know why it thinks port 5000 is in use since it works outside of docker. I tried restarting but that didn't help. I also tried killing the process but the process that seems to own port 5000 just restarts. But I am confused here because localhost:5000 works just fine if I use npm start.

```
➜  app-flask git:(implementation) ✗ lsof -i:5000
COMMAND   PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 745 <me>    7u  IPv4 0x3d5df920d91eb581      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 745 <me>    8u  IPv6 0x3d5df925a4daac49      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
➜  app-flask git:(<me>) ✗ kill 745
➜  app-flask git:(<me>) ✗ lsof -i:5000
COMMAND     PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 10675 <me>    7u  IPv4 0x3d5df920d9d8e1c1      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 10675 <me>    8u  IPv6 0x3d5df925a1176c49      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Additional info. `docker ps` output:

> ➜   docker ps -a CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS
> PORTS     NAMES
>
> ➜  docker run -p 5000:5000 app-flask docker: Error response from
> daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 ->
> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
>
> ➜   docker ps -a                      CONTAINER ID   IMAGE
> COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
> 6d813f5c4487   app-flask   "python3 -m flask ru…"   9 seconds ago
> Created             keen_mirzakhani

Comment: What does `docker ps -a` show?

Comment: Your `lsof` output seems to clearly show that something on your host (`ControlCe`) is listening on port 5000. That seems to be the your problem.

Comment: ➜   docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

➜  docker run -p 5000:5000 app-flask
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:5000 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5000: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 

➜   docker ps -a                     
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
6d813f5c4487   app-flask   "python3 -m flask ru…"   9 seconds ago   Created             keen_mirzakhani

Comment: @HansKilian Sorry, I can't make my comment multiline. Basically `docker ps -a` output is empty before I start the container.

Comment: You could edit your post and add the information if you want better formatting

Comment: @larsks yes that's why I'm confused. the process keeps restarting when I kill it. but npm isn't bothered by it.

Comment: @Pino yes that helps. Now I just don't understand why it still works with npm. Thanks for that post.

Comment: If `npm start` starts a dev server listening on `127.0.0.1:5000`, that doesn't immediately conflict with the host service on `0.0.0.0:5000`.